# Uncaught syntax error on closing div in wordpress 5.0

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to add custom block in wordpress 5.0 which is having gutenberg.

I am following below link but the code of ESNext is not working for me. It is giving me the syntax error. 
Link: https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/

Below is my functions.php code :

```
function gutenberg_boilerplate_block() {
    wp_register_script(
        'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5-step01',
        get_template_directory_uri().'/step-01/block.js',
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element' )
    );

    register_block_type( 'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5/hello-world-step-01', array(
        'editor_script' => 'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5-step01',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'gutenberg_boilerplate_block' );
```

My js file is block.js and below is the code of that file :

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const blockStyle = { backgroundColor: '#900', color: '#fff', padding: '20px' };

registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-boilerplate-esnext/hello-world-step-01', {
    title: 'Hello World (Step 1)',

    icon: 'universal-access-alt',

    category: 'layout',

    edit() {
        return <p> Test </p>;
    },

    save() {
        return <p> Test </p>;
    },
} )
```

The problem is at the closing HTML Tag.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can not use ESNext directly, you need a transpiler like babel to convert esnext into es2015. Wordpress can not consume esnext directly.